# didReceiveLocalNotification: being called more than once for the same notification

Tags: ios

My application queues local notifications using UIApplication scheduleLocalNotification:.

I'm currently queuing two notifications (which have different content) with the same fire time, but didReceiveLocalNotification: is being called twice for the 2nd notification.

I have 100% confirmed, and quadruple checked, by setting breakpoints and logging statements that scheduleLocalNotification: is only getting called twice. 
Yet still I am receiving didReceiveLocalNotification calls twice for the same notification (i.e. didReceiveLocalNotification is called 3 times in total).

This only happens if the two local notifications have the same fire time - if they are different things are ok.

I am puzzled. Any ideas?

With reference to this:
[local notification "didReceiveLocalNotification" calls twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227080/local-notification-didreceivelocalnotification-calls-twice)

for me it happens on hardware and the state is the same.

Comment: same here: every time I open the app, this method is called. Have no clue, is this a bug? (i am using iPhone6s)

Comment: This is a long time ago now, but I think in end I had to stagger the fire times in order to avoid there being duplicates.

Comment: how did you solve this ?

Comment: As it says in the comment directly above