# iOS – UILocalNotification fired twice for same notification

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

If I schedule two `UILocalNotification`s and set them both to fire at the exact same fireDate. Then on the device (this is not the simulator bug) on the fireDate the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` will fire 4 times (2 times for each notification). Is this a known bug? Because I have not been able to find any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please report the bug to http://bugreport.apple.com.

Having said that, it has been noticed before that while there is the bug in the simulator there also appears to be a bug on the device.

See the comments and answers on this SO question: [local notification "didReceiveLocalNotification" calls twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3227080/558933)

Answer (score 0):

try this it's work in my application :

```
-(IBAction)setRemind:(id)sender{

NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

//Gets our picker
NSDate *selectedTime = [datePicker date];
strDate2 = [dateFormatter2 stringFromDate:selectedTime];
NSDate *Date=[dateFormatter2 dateFromString:strDate2];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:Date];

// Set up the fire time
NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComp setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[dateComp setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[dateComp setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[dateComp setHour:9];
[dateComp setMinute:00];
[dateComp setSecond:00];
[dateComp release];

NSDate *date = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComp];
[self scheduleAlarmForDate:date message:txtDescri.text];

}


-(IBAction)scheduleAlarmForDate:(NSDate*)date message:(NSString*)msg
{

//====== TO SEE OLD NOTIFI=======
UIApplication *Ap = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *arr = [Ap scheduledLocalNotifications];
NSLog(@"Old Notifications :>> %@",arr);

UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

// Create a new notification
alarm.fireDate = date;
NSLog(@"fireDate IS >> %@", alarm.fireDate);
alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
alarm.alertBody = msg;
NSLog(@"msg IS >> %@",msg);
alarm.alertAction = @"Show";
alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
alarm.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
[app scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
 [alarm release];
}
```

i Hope it's helpful to you.