# Notification in iphone app

Tags: ios, notifications

I have read many post of notification but somehow i am going wrong somewhere so that's why i post this question. I want to get daily notification at 9.00 am in my app. I get it properly at 9.00 am with no problem what so ever but the difficulty is that i also get same notification at 2.00 am. I try with following code. Can anyone tell me where i am getting wrong. Or is it problem of ios6. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thank you.

```
    NSString *day =@"9:00 AM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    //NSTimeZone *gmt = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
    //[dateFormat setTimeZone:gmt];
    NSDate *today=[dateFormat dateFromString:day];
    NSLog(@"string %@ & date %@",day,today);
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil)
    {
        // delObj.QCouter=delObj.QCouter+1;

        //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
        notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate =today;
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
         NSLog(@"timeZone %@ ",[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]);
        notif.alertBody = @"You have a new letter ";
        notif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);;
        notif.soundName = @"Ding3.wav";
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Status"];
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"You have a notifiaction"
                                                                       forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;
        // NSLog(@"userInfo %@",notif.userInfo);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"CurrentDay" forKey:@"DayChange"];
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try following code:-

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate: date];
    [components setHour: 9];
    [components setMinute: 0];
    [components setSecond: 0];

    NSDate *today = [gregorian dateFromComponents: components];
    [gregorian release];

    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil)
    {
        notif = [[cls alloc] init];
        notif.fireDate =today;
        notif.alertBody = @"You have a new letter ";
        notif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);;
        notif.soundName = @"Ding3.wav";
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"1" forKey:@"Status"];
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"You have a notifiaction"
                                                                       forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;
        // NSLog(@"userInfo %@",notif.userInfo);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [notif release];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"CurrentDay" forKey:@"DayChange"];
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simulator or real device?

Simulator has a known bug where it generates two "fires" of a single notification. If that's what's happening, try it on a physical device and see if the same behavior occurs. It's annoying, but not an actual problem with your app. (Assuming it's the simulator, of course!)

See this question: [iOS – UILocalNotification fired twice for same notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430669/ios-uilocalnotification-fired-twice-for-same-notification)

Edit based on "not in the simulator":

try adding a call to this after you schedule the notification, and see if some other part of your code is slipping in another scheduled item you're not aware of:

```
- (void) _debug_logExistingToConsole
{
    if (LOG) NSLog(@"Notifications set is now: \n");
    UIApplication *Ap = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray* arr = [Ap scheduledLocalNotifications];
    if (LOG) NSLog(@"%@", arr);
}
```

Comment: And you're 100% certain the notification code isn't running twice?

Comment: Looking at the code I wonder about the implications of scheduling based on a date initialized with just a time string (no date specifier) and the fact that you're scheduling it as a daily repeat. Perhaps eliminating one or the other (or both) of those elements would make the "double" go away, giving you something to focus on...

Comment: it gives notification at 9 am and 2 am

Comment: i want daily notification at 9 am.