# Local Notification Displays Twice

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

There are times when my app's local notification is fired (displayed) twice. I'm not using a simulator but a real device. I've been trying to get a repro step but i couldn't make it. Every time i follow through the process with a breakpoint/nslog i always get 1 notification scheduled. With this, i assume that i would only get 1 notification displayed/fired. However, there are times when i get two notifications.
I have searched for answers on the internet and I couldn't get much info. Has anyone here experienced the same thing? How were you able to solve the problem?

```
- (void)scheduleAllNotifications
{
    if (_isEnabled && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:NotificationsUserDefaultsKey]) {
        [self updateFireDates];
        for (NSDate *fireDate in fireDates) {
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
            notification.fireDate = fireDate;
            notification.alertBody = @"Message";
            notification.alertAction = @"View";
            notification.soundName = @"notificationsound.mp3";
            [notifications addObject:notification];

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
}



- (void)cancelAllNotifications
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [notifications removeAllObjects];

}

- (void)updateFireDates
{
    [fireDates removeAllObjects];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:THREEDAYS sinceDate:now];
    if (fireDate){[fireDates addObject:fireDate];}
}
```

cancelAllNotifications is called every time app becomes active
shceduleAllNotifications is called every time the app resigns active

Comment: Show your code how adding and checking the notifications.

Comment: i already added my code. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Bart Doe is right, these are stray notifications from previous test runs.

To fix the issue, call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` in the AppDelegate within `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, in order to purge all previous scheduled notifications.

Comment: Same problem here. Stray notifications. All I did was uninstall the app and they were gone once I installed again. Hope it doesn't happens when in production.

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be in the building/debugging phase of your project, it wouldn't surprise me if these double notifications are actually old ones. It happened to me that I thought the device created weird, stray notifications, when actually during development/testing I created wrong ones myself.

What you can do, is put some extra debugging information in the userInfo field. You can put the build number in there, or the creation date/time, that sort of stuff. Then log these whenever the notification fires.

You might truly have encountered a bug, though:
[local notification "didReceiveLocalNotification" calls twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227080/local-notification-didreceivelocalnotification-calls-twice)

Comment: actually, i'm not in the debugging state when it happened. i was just playing with it after it has been released.